# XML: Splitting up a string into two fields

Tags: xml

We receive a CSV file from a company daily, to deliver their orders.  Presently, the city and state are separated into two fields, CITY and STATE, found in columns I & J.  (e.g. ...,"BANGOR","ME",...)

A change in the software will merge these two fields into one, CITY+STATE, which will be in column I. (e.g. ...,"BANGOR ME",...)

Our XML config is built to the old format...

```
<Map Col="I" Fld="(...)" Title="CITY" Validate="Required"/>
<Map Col="J" Fld="(...)" Title="STATE" Validate="Required"/>
```

The goal here is for the XML Config to take the last two characters of column I for the state, and the remainder for the city.  Thoughts?

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) The software change is a step backwards -- better to maintain separate elements for separate datum.  (2) XML itself cannot convert or split; see XSLT or an XML library within your favorite programming language.

Comment: What programming language?  How do you handle  Frostbite Falls, Minnesota?

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  (1) I agree with you, but the customer's software made the change.  I'm just trying to adapt.  (2)  I just started learning XSLT; I'll start there.